# What to do after installing Gmapping

Tags: navigation, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
what is the next step after installing the Gmapping package from (GitHub)
i install it in a workspace,

---

my lidar is working with Rviz
,,
what is next ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/274537/what-to-do-after-installing-gmapping/) by [marawy_alsakaf](https://answers.ros.org/users/31902/marawy_alsakaf/) on ROS Answers with karma: 101 on 2017-10-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Perhaps start playing with this package? Look at it's documentation [here](http://wiki.ros.org/gmapping). It will give you info about the system. Then it's up to you to play with it.

---

Originally posted by [l4ncelot](https://answers.ros.org/users/23971/l4ncelot/) with karma: 826 on 2017-10-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2